# How to lock a specific map's index for concurent Read/Write in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, parallel-processing, mutex

I wanted to know if there is a way to lock only an index in a map during concurrent read/write. I am pretty new to Golang and parallelism sorry if the answer is obvious.

```
func Check(a, b []string) map[string]int {
    var res = make(map[string]int)
    go func() {
        for _, v := range a {
            res[v]++
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for _, v := range b {
            res[v]++
        }
    }()
    return res
}
```

Eventually this piece of code is going to panic due to concurrent map Read/Write. So we should add mutex to lock the map.

```
var m sync.Mutex
go func() {
    for _, v := range a {
        m.Lock()
        res[v]++
        m.Unlock()
    }
}()
go func() {
    for _, v := range b {
        m.Lock()
        res[v]++
        m.Unlock()
    }
}()
```

But from my understanding `m.lock()` will lock my whole map? Isn't this too much overhead by locking everything? This bugged me as i thought this piece of code may not be faster than running linearly. Can I possibly lock only the map at `map["some key"]`, so that my second goroutine can still write in `map["some other key"]`?

Comment: You can't lock only a single entry of a map, because writing another may cause an internal restructuring that may effect other entries as well, including the one you intend to lock.

Comment: And in fact you can't lock the whole map either. You lock the mutex. What that mutex controls access to is entirely determined by how you use it. You *could* create a mutex for every key in the map, which would allow you per-entry granularity of locking, but as icza noted, that wouldn't actually prevent data races.

Comment: Thanks ! Your replies helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

From [GO 1.9 Release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#sync-map)

## Concurrent Map

The new Map type in the sync package is a concurrent map with amortized-constant-time loads, stores, and deletes. It is safe for multiple goroutines to call a Map's methods concurrently.

GO Team built one for you!

Answer (score 2):

Maps themselves do not take care of locks, therefore any manipulation of them on multiple go routines (or reading while they are being manipulated) will require some for of syncing (e.g., `sync.Mutex`). There are fancier things you can do though.

## RW Mutex

You can get a little fancier depending on your use case and use a `sync.RWMutex`. This will allow concurrent reads while safely blocking for any write. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := map[int]int{}
    lock := sync.RWMutex{}

    go func() {
        // Writer
        for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
            // Notice that this uses Lock and NOT RLock
            lock.Lock()
            m[5]++
            m[6] += 2
            lock.Unlock()
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
            lock.RLock()
            println(m[5])
            lock.RUnlock()
        }
    }()

    for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
        lock.RLock()
        println(m[6])
        lock.RUnlock()
    }
}
```

This does not give you a key by key locking mechanism though.

## sync.Map

The `sync.Map` is provided by the standard library and is robust. It has more fine grained locking.

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := sync.Map{}

    go func() {
        // Writer
        for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
            value, _ := m.LoadOrStore(5, 0)
            m.Store(5, value.(int)+1)
            value, _ = m.LoadOrStore(6, 0)
            m.Store(6, value.(int)+2)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
            value, _ := m.LoadOrStore(5, 0)
            println(value.(int))
        }
    }()

    for range time.Tick(250 * time.Millisecond) {
        value, _ := m.LoadOrStore(6, 0)
        println(value.(int))
    }
}
```

Notice that the code doesn't have any mutexes. Also notice that you get to deal with empty interfaces...